# The anchor tag in html is bugged or something

Tags: html, browser

So when I was trying to link to a page using the  tag and tried testing it and clicking on it, nothing happened like I literally mean nothing happened.

```
<a src="https://google.com"><button>Google</button></a>
```

So I tried making the anchor tag by it self and when I refreshed the page it just acted like a passage tag

and have just text and can't click on it and when I right click it it just shows the default context menu for text so how can I fix it because it shouldn't be doing this and it is showing now error or anything and tried it with multiple browsers and nothing is working. And I said I tried the  tag by itself so that means it has nothing to do with the css and I also tried the target attr as well and still nothing. I tried through localhost and file and still nothing so I am out of ideas now.

Comment: It's not `src`, it's `href`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/Creating_hyperlinks#Anatomy_of_a_link

Comment: My mistake...I was working with audio before that and might of got confused.